# Codeblocks says "the path you entered seems valid, but this wizard can't locate the following SDL's include file: SDL/SDL.h?"

Tags: sdl, codeblocks, sdl-2

I'm going through the normal process of naming the program, choosing the directory to install it in, but then it asks me for the location of SDL's include and lib library. I am currently storing my installation of SDL at C: directory but when I type in C:\SDL2-2.0.5\i686-w64-mingw32 as it asks me for the path to the lib and include files, I get the error. How can I stop CodeBlocks from returning the error?

SPECIFICS: 
SDL2.5

Error: the path you entered seems valid, but this wizard can't locate the following SDL's include file: SDL/SDL.h?

Comment: if you are using sdl2, correct me if i'm wrong, but isn't the path SDL2/SDL.h ? and second, is there an actual path you can browse to C:\SDL2-2.0.5\i686-w64-mingw32\SDL\SDL.h ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if changing the include path to C:\SDL2-2.0.5\i686-w64-mingw32\include works. Most libraries include the header files in the /include directory and the libraries in the /lib directory.

Also, I believe the windows version of the binaries have the additional "SDL2/" before the headers whereas the mingw version, that you're using, does not (I can't remember off the top of my head).